# ArgumentException when istantiate SoapService only in built android app with UNITY3d

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, soap, wsdl

I made a Unity Game that call a service for obtain a game data.
When starting the game from unity player it works fine, but when I build apk and run it on android device I get error in logCat:

> Error Unity: ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: ':Users:::'  Key being added: ':Users:::'
>
> Error Unity:   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert (System.Object key, System.Object nvalue, System.Boolean add) [0x001d4] in <599589bf4ce248909b8a14cbe4a2034e>:0
>
> Error Unity:   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Add (System.Object key, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <599589bf4ce248909b8a14cbe4a2034e>:0
>
> Error Unity:   at System.Collections.DictionaryBase.System.Collections.IDictionary.Add (System.Object key, System.Object value) [0x00016] in <599589bf4ce248909b8a14cbe4a2034e>:0
>
> Error Unity:   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly+TempMethodDictionary.Add (System.String key, System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly+TempMethod value) [0x00006] in :0
>
> Error Unity:   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.InitAssemblyMethods (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMapping[] xmlMappings) [0x00063] in :0
>
> Error Unity:   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Sy

For calling a service I've created a WebClient Folder with System.Web.Services.dll and wsdl-c# file generated via command.

Here is the ServiceSoap.cs file content:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "0.0.0.0")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "ServizioNumbersSoap", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
public partial class ServizioNumbers : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
{

    private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback getSolutionsbyGridOperationCompleted;

    private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback getGridOperationCompleted;

    private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback getUserOperationCompleted;

    private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback setUsersOperationCompleted;

    private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback updUserScore1OperationCompleted;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ServizioNumbers()
    {
        this.Url = "http://numbers.jemaka.it/NumberService.asmx";
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public event getSolutionsbyGridCompletedEventHandler getSolutionsbyGridCompleted;

    /// <remarks/>
    public event getGridCompletedEventHandler getGridCompleted;

    /// <remarks/>
    public event getUserCompletedEventHandler getUserCompleted;

    /// <remarks/>
    public event setUsersCompletedEventHandler setUsersCompleted;

    /// <remarks/>
    public event updUserScore1CompletedEventHandler updUserScore1Completed;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/getSolutionsbyGrid", RequestNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public Solutions[] getSolutionsbyGrid(int idGrid)
    {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("getSolutionsbyGrid", new object[] {
                    idGrid});
        return ((Solutions[])(results[0]));
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void getSolutionsbyGridAsync(int idGrid)
    {
        this.getSolutionsbyGridAsync(idGrid, null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void getSolutionsbyGridAsync(int idGrid, object userState)
    {
        if ((this.getSolutionsbyGridOperationCompleted == null))
        {
            this.getSolutionsbyGridOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OngetSolutionsbyGridOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("getSolutionsbyGrid", new object[] {
                    idGrid}, this.getSolutionsbyGridOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OngetSolutionsbyGridOperationCompleted(object arg)
    {
        if ((this.getSolutionsbyGridCompleted != null))
        {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.getSolutionsbyGridCompleted(this, new getSolutionsbyGridCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/getGrid", RequestNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public Grids getGrid()
    {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("getGrid", new object[0]);
        return ((Grids)(results[0]));
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void getGridAsync()
    {
        this.getGridAsync(null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void getGridAsync(object userState)
    {
        if ((this.getGridOperationCompleted == null))
        {
            this.getGridOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OngetGridOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("getGrid", new object[0], this.getGridOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OngetGridOperationCompleted(object arg)
    {
        if ((this.getGridCompleted != null))
        {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.getGridCompleted(this, new getGridCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/getUser", RequestNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public Users getUser(string uuid)
    {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("getUser", new object[] {
                    uuid});
        return ((Users)(results[0]));
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void getUserAsync(string uuid)
    {
        this.getUserAsync(uuid, null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void getUserAsync(string uuid, object userState)
    {
        if ((this.getUserOperationCompleted == null))
        {
            this.getUserOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OngetUserOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("getUser", new object[] {
                    uuid}, this.getUserOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OngetUserOperationCompleted(object arg)
    {
        if ((this.getUserCompleted != null))
        {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.getUserCompleted(this, new getUserCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/setUsers", RequestNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public string setUsers(Users u)
    {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("setUsers", new object[] {
                    u});
        return ((string)(results[0]));
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void setUsersAsync(Users u)
    {
        this.setUsersAsync(u, null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void setUsersAsync(Users u, object userState)
    {
        if ((this.setUsersOperationCompleted == null))
        {
            this.setUsersOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnsetUsersOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("setUsers", new object[] {
                    u}, this.setUsersOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OnsetUsersOperationCompleted(object arg)
    {
        if ((this.setUsersCompleted != null))
        {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.setUsersCompleted(this, new setUsersCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/updUserScore1", RequestNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public void updUserScore1(int id_user, float score1)
    {
        this.Invoke("updUserScore1", new object[] {
                    id_user,
                    score1});
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void updUserScore1Async(int id_user, float score1)
    {
        this.updUserScore1Async(id_user, score1, null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void updUserScore1Async(int id_user, float score1, object userState)
    {
        if ((this.updUserScore1OperationCompleted == null))
        {
            this.updUserScore1OperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnupdUserScore1OperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("updUserScore1", new object[] {
                    id_user,
                    score1}, this.updUserScore1OperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OnupdUserScore1OperationCompleted(object arg)
    {
        if ((this.updUserScore1Completed != null))
        {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.updUserScore1Completed(this, new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public new void CancelAsync(object userState)
    {
        base.CancelAsync(userState);
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "0.0.0.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
public partial class Solutions
{

    private int id_solutionField;

    private int id_gridField;

    private float numberField;

    private string sequenceField;

    private float difficultyField;

    private string noteField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int Id_solution
    {
        get
        {
            return this.id_solutionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.id_solutionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public int Id_grid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.id_gridField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.id_gridField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public float Number
    {
        get
        {
            return this.numberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.numberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Sequence
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sequenceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sequenceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public float Difficulty
    {
        get
        {
            return this.difficultyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.difficultyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Note
    {
        get
        {
            return this.noteField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.noteField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "0.0.0.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
public partial class Users
{

    private int id_userField;

    private string nicknameField;

    private string imeiField;

    private string uuidField;

    private System.DateTime data_setupField;

    private string emailField;

    private string service_idField;

    private string noteField;

    private float score1Field;

    private float score2Field;

    private float bonus1Field;

    private float bonus2Field;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int Id_user
    {
        get
        {
            return this.id_userField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.id_userField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Nickname
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nicknameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nicknameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Imei
    {
        get
        {
            return this.imeiField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.imeiField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Uuid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uuidField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uuidField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public System.DateTime Data_setup
    {
        get
        {
            return this.data_setupField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.data_setupField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return this.emailField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.emailField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Service_id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.service_idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.service_idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Note
    {
        get
        {
            return this.noteField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.noteField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public float Score1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.score1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.score1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public float Score2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.score2Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.score2Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public float Bonus1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bonus1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bonus1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public float Bonus2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bonus2Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bonus2Field = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "0.0.0.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
public partial class Grids
{

    private int id_gridField;

    private string itemField;

    private System.DateTime data_creationField;

    private float difficultyField;

    private Solutions solutionsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int Id_grid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.id_gridField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.id_gridField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public System.DateTime Data_creation
    {
        get
        {
            return this.data_creationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.data_creationField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public float Difficulty
    {
        get
        {
            return this.difficultyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.difficultyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public Solutions Solutions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.solutionsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.solutionsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "0.0.0.0")]
public delegate void getSolutionsbyGridCompletedEventHandler(object sender, getSolutionsbyGridCompletedEventArgs e);

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "0.0.0.0")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class getSolutionsbyGridCompletedEventArgs : System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs
{

    private object[] results;

    internal getSolutionsbyGridCompletedEventArgs(object[] results, System.Exception exception, bool cancelled, object userState) :
            base(exception, cancelled, userState)
    {
        this.results = results;
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public Solutions[] Result
    {
        get
        {
            this.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary();
            return ((Solutions[])(this.results[0]));
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "0.0.0.0")]
public delegate void getGridCompletedEventHandler(object sender, getGridCompletedEventArgs e);

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "0.0.0.0")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class getGridCompletedEventArgs : System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs
{

    private object[] results;

    internal getGridCompletedEventArgs(object[] results, System.Exception exception, bool cancelled, object userState) :
            base(exception, cancelled, userState)
    {
        this.results = results;
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public Grids Result
    {
        get
        {
            this.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary();
            return ((Grids)(this.results[0]));
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "0.0.0.0")]
public delegate void getUserCompletedEventHandler(object sender, getUserCompletedEventArgs e);

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "0.0.0.0")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class getUserCompletedEventArgs : System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs
{

    private object[] results;

    internal getUserCompletedEventArgs(object[] results, System.Exception exception, bool cancelled, object userState) :
            base(exception, cancelled, userState)
    {
        this.results = results;
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public Users Result
    {
        get
        {
            this.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary();
            return ((Users)(this.results[0]));
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "0.0.0.0")]
public delegate void setUsersCompletedEventHandler(object sender, setUsersCompletedEventArgs e);

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "0.0.0.0")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class setUsersCompletedEventArgs : System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs
{

    private object[] results;

    internal setUsersCompletedEventArgs(object[] results, System.Exception exception, bool cancelled, object userState) :
            base(exception, cancelled, userState)
    {
        this.results = results;
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Result
    {
        get
        {
            this.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary();
            return ((string)(this.results[0]));
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "0.0.0.0")]
public delegate void updUserScore1CompletedEventHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e);
```

for calling service in GameManger.cs I do this:

```cs
     void Start()
    {
       srv = new ServizioNumbers(); <--- Here handle's error
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?!

**I posted the SOAP client code I defined in the game, in order to allow anyone to reproduce the problem.**

Comment: As now, your questions has a lot of code, and that makes others hard to reproduce the problem and pinpoint the cause. Check the [mcve] help page. From your error description, it tries to deserialize something into a `c#` class but fails because of the data (probably duplicated users). If you could narrow your question with a sample of what did return the SOAP and your `c#` classes structure it would be wise.

Comment: bradbury9, tnx for reply, but my question is: why from unity player work fine, Without any error?

Comment: Probably the received or sent data is somehow different when you went into unity.., but there is no WSDL in your question yet your error stack trace points to that data.

Comment: thank you for your patience, and forgive my mistakes in defining the problem, it is the first time I ask for help here. Is it okay if I post the WSDL web address here?

[My service WSDL](http://numbers.jemaka.it/NumberService.asmx?wsdl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really use WSDL, SOAP or XML serialization on mobile platforms. Try using the `Mono` runtime option in Android with the latest (4.5) .net Runtime. You will not be able to use `il2cpp`.

Comment: tnx, DoctorPangloss, but I see only NET4.X and NET2.0 options in API Level selection......How I can call a service asmx in Unity?!? I've The same problem if i build the game standalone for windows....seems work only with unity player.....

Comment: ok, resolved converting SOAP service to REST API and adding a REST client logic (JSON) to my game! tnx!